# How close to a Restricted Area can a pilot be cleared to fly?

Tags: faa-regulations, special-use-airspace

In my local area there is an instrument approach that skirts the edge of a restricted area by a mile or two. The TRACON for this approach is *not* the controlling agency for the restricted area. When the restricted area is active, the TRACON will not give clearance for the instrument approach unless the weather is VMC. Is there a requirement that ATC cannot have pilots flying too close to Prohibited/Restricted areas in IMC? Even if they're flying a published procedure?

Is this different for VFR flights?

Comment: *"TRACON will not give clearance for the instrument approach unless the weather is VMC"* You mean *unless the weather is **IMC***?

Comment: Negative. They will not allow us to fly close to the restricted area *unless* we are VMC (they might have us cancel IFR)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ATC will separate IFR traffic from active special-use airspace according to the separation minima prescribed in the [7110.65 9–3–2:](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap9_section_3.html#u4M1b8JACK)

- **Vertical separation:** 500 feet above or below a prohibited/restricted/warning/MOA/ATCAA/ALTRV area (1000 feet above or below, if above FL290).
- **Radar separation:** 3 miles from the periphery of special-use airspace; or for specific areas that have been designated by management as not needing 3 miles, simply "clear of" the periphery.
- **Non-radar separation:** On airways whose protected airspace does not overlap the special-use airspace. (Remember that Federal airways extend [four or more miles](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pham_html/chap20_section_3.html) from each side of the centerline.)

Note that VFR traffic are explicitly mentioned as *not* prohibited from flying through a [transitional hazard area](https://123atc.com/term/transitional-hazard-area-tha) (a term I think is used in conjunction with spacecraft launch and reentry). It is also "common knowledge" that VFR aircraft may fly through an active MOA but not active R- or P-airspace; however I can't seem to find anything that says this explicitly. R- and P- airspace is discussed at [14 CFR 91.133](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.133), which does not mention MOAs.

---

Without knowing the specific situation you're talking about, my guess is that when the restricted area is hot the TRACON is withholding an approach clearance using that approach for *all IFR aircraft* whether IMC or VMC, and only permitting VFR practice approaches to use it.

Answer (score 1):

> Restricted Areas (...) If the restricted area is active and **has not been released** to the controlling agency (FAA), **the ATC facility will issue a clearance** which will ensure the aircraft avoids the restricted airspace **unless** it is on an approved altitude reservation mission or has obtained its own permission to operate in the airspace and so informs the controlling facility. ([AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap3_section_4.html))

How close you can fly, per the AIM's wording above, is not a distance, rather up to the ATC's instructions, unless the mentioned waivers apply. Checking 14 CFR:

> (...) Upon the request of the FAA, the using agency shall execute a letter **establishing procedures** for joint use of a restricted area by the using agency and the controlling agency (...) [14 CFR § 73.15](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/73.15)

Which means the established procedures, like the regular one you encounter, are coordinated between the using agency and the FAA.

Regarding VFR flights, restricted areas are not wholly prohibited:

> (...) while not wholly prohibited (...) Penetration of restricted areas without authorization from the using or controlling agency may be **extremely hazardous** to the aircraft and its occupants. ([AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap3_section_4.html))

---

To summarize:

- How close is managed by the ATC (see @randomhead 's [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84786/14897))
- ATC's actions are already coordinated with the using agency
- While not wholly prohibited, restricted areas may be extremely hazardous.